How to know how many argument vsnprintf has used, if buffer size is less than actual size needed?
I am trying to break the message into chunks of 32bytes, i am using vsnprintf to print the message. But the args are not incrementing i.e. even after calling vsnprintf the args show the first argument.
#define NOR_LOG_MSG_LENGTH      32
void NOR_LOG_MSG(const char* msg, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);
    uint8_t tempMsgBuf[NOR_LOG_MSG_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    int m = vsnprintf((char*)tempMsgBuf, NOR_LOG_MSG_LENGTH, msg, args);
        //I want to use rest of the args in next vsnprintf
    va_end(args);
}

So, the real question here is, if the vsnprintf increment the args after using it? How should i know how many arguments have been used and how many are left so that i can call va_arg to increment the args?

I am trying to break the message into chunks of 32bytes That sounds fundamentally broken.  How could you break up something like "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" into 32-bit chunks using multiple calls when any one output can cross a 32-byte boundary?  Just make one call to vsnprintf() and cut the resulting string into 32-byte strings.

That's not how vsnprintf works, at all. You can't use it like that.

As @dbush says, format the entire output in a big enough buffer, then process the result in 32-byte chunks.  All else apart, arranging the extra calls to vsnprintf() with the appropriate subset of the format string and argument list will be nasty to code; I doubt if it can be done correctly for the general case, though it might be possible for a restricted subset.  The “format it all and split the result” technique will work reliably.

What you're trying to do won't work.  There's no way to know how far you got through the format string, or even if a particular format specifier was able to print all necessary characters.
What you need to do instead is first call vsnprintf with NULL for the first argument and 0 for the second.  This will return the number of bytes required to store the resulting string without actually writing anything.  Then dynamically allocate the necessary space and call it again, making sure to use a separate va_start and va_end set.
void NOR_LOG_MSG(const char* msg, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);
    int m = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, msg, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (m < 0) return;

    uint8_t *buff = malloc(m + 1);
    if (!buff) return;
    va_start(args, msg);
    vsnprintf(buff, m + 1, msg, args);
    va_end(args);

    // use buff
    free(buf);
}


"first call snprintf" --> "first call vsnprintf"

Pedantic code would check if m < 0.

Linux and BSD provide the vasprintf() function and remove the need to call vsnprintf() twice.

Can you use va_start twice? Isn't it UB?va_copy is to have copy of args.

@0___________ It's fine if you call va_end first before calling va_start again.

@0___________ 7.16.1.4p3: "Neither the va_start nor va_copy macro shall be invoked to reinitialize ap
without an intervening invocation of the va_end macro for the same ap"
